# How to replace matched character String in java?

Tags: java, java-io

I have a question about how to replace String when matched character found. In this case, i read java file that contains variable which marked with underscore. Here the java file:

```
 public int[][] initArray(int rows, int cols, int init_value)
{
 int[][] _bb = (int[][])null;
 if ((rows > 1) && (cols > 1)) {
   _bb = new int[rows][cols];
   for (int _ii = 0; _ii < rows; _ii++) {
     for (int _ee = 0; _ee < cols; _ee++) {
       _bb[_ii][_ee] = init_value;
     }
   }
 } else {
   warning("Array length must be greater than zero!");
 }
 return _bb;
}
```

All of variable that contain underscore will be replaced with generate string. Well, then this is the code that i have used to read that file and replace matched string:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

if (line.contains(" _") && line.contains(";")) {

    String get = varname(line);

    RandomString r = new RandomString();

    String[] split = get.split("\\s+");
    String gvarname = split[0];

   ss = "_"+gvarname;
   map.put(ss, "l"+r.generateRandomString());

   for(String key: map.keySet()){
       if(line.contains(key)){
           line = line.replace(key, map.get(key));

       }
   }
```

Then, this is a method to get an index of variable name:

```
String varname(String str){
    int startIdx = str.indexOf("_");
    int endIdx = str.indexOf(';');

    String content = str.substring(startIdx + 1, endIdx);
    return content;
}
```

Actually above code is working and replace some variables name, but some character noted matched when i put space example _bb[_ii] is not working, but _bb[ _ii ] is working. I don't know how, help me!

Thanks

Comment: Show us sample input and expected output

Comment: `line.replaceAll("\\s+_",";")`?

Comment: @Vinod Madyalkar Well, i reading java file using JAVA IO. the point is i want to replace all matched string. Example i read java file that contain string _ii, then i will replace all matched _ii with new String.

Comment: @SamsulArifin - Then kevin's soultion should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to recognize the entire variable, here using `\b` to find word boundaries.

```
public class Obfuscate {

    private static final Pattern VAR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\b_(\\w+)\\b");
    private final Map<String, String> renames = new HashMap<>();

    public String obfuscate(String sourceCode) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(sourceCode.length() + 100);
        Matcher m = VAR_PATTERN.matcher(sourceCode);
        while (m.find()) {
            String var = m.group(1);
            String newVar = renames.get(var);
            if (newVar == null) {
                newVar = randomVar();
                renames.put(var, newVar);
            }
            m.appendReplacement(buf, newVar);
        }
        m.appendTail(buf);
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

A map is needed to match the same old variable to the same new name.

A `Set<String>` of new names might be needed to check that the generated name does not repeat.

Your approach of doing a `replaceAll` of the same var is fine too, but requires reading all. The method above can be repeated (say per line), hence the map as field.

Comment: I think your regex won't recognize all occurrences (e.g. `_ii` in `[_ii]`)

Comment: @sina I think it does: word-boundary, underscore, group 1 (one-or-more word-characters), word-boundary. The last word-boundary not even needed. Square braces should be no problem, neither underscore inside or _i.

Comment: My apologies, it obviously does (even checked the definition of \b now to be sure ;). It was an error on my side - online regex checkers are nice, but one should be able to configure them correctly.

Comment: @sina yes, `\b` is useful to know, and has nothing to do with blank/backspace or so.

Comment: @Joop Eggen, i have tried your code. But nothing happened. Am i worng?
This is my sample code to call the method:

if(line.contains(" _") && line.contains(";")){
                        String get = varname(line);
                        
                        String[] split = get.split("\\s+");
                        String gvarname = split[0];

                       Obfuscate rn = new Obfuscate();
                        rn.obfuscate(gvarname);

Comment: You must use the result of `m.obfuscate(gvarname)`` - also it will replace all variables in the given string, so you are doing too much.

Comment: @Joop Eggen, thanks a lot, now is working! Great code!! 
Your code  so cool :)

Answer (score 0):

In your first `if`-statement you check if the string contains `" _"` (an underscore with a leading space).

If in the following line of your source-java-file

```
       _bb[_ii][_ee] = init_value;
```

`_bb...` is indented with tabulators, `<tab>_bb` will not match `<space>_bb`. There is no leading space before `_ii` and `_ee` either, so the `if` returns `false`.

If you put a space between `[` and `_ii`, you find a match for `<space>_ii` and your `if` results in `true` and executes your replacement code.

If you are sure that there will be no other use of an underscore in your source text other than as a replacement indicator, you can simply remove the space from your if-condition and use `line.contains("_")` instead.

Btw: Are you sure that you want to check that the line must contain a `;` aswell? What if your source text contains a line like `while(_xx==true) {`?

Also, because of

```
String[] split = get.split("\\s+");
String gvarname = split[0];
```

your code is not able to split a line like `_bb[_ii][_ee]` correctly (and even if it would be, because of `split[0]` you would only replace the first identifier you found, subsequent ones would be ignored). Your split searches for spaces and the source line doesn't contain any. Again, you could probably change this and split for underscores (this would return an array containing `bb[`, `ii][` and `ee]`) and then loop every returned array element until you find the first character that can't be part of your variable identifier (e.g. until the first non-alphanumeric character).

An `_` plus the part of the array element up to that non-alphanumeric character is then the identifier that you want to replace.